# What is the meaning of the word mapping in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

In the book titled *What the Future and Why It's up To Us* by Tim O'Reilly there is a line as follows:

> How can we all become better at mapping future trends?

Here a keyword in this sentence is the verb "mapping". What does it mean by "mapping future trends"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly the oldest sense of the word ***mapping*** there is, just it's used figuratively here.

When one explores land and makes a map of it, that is *mapping*.

Thus *mapping future trends* is looking at the metaphorical "lay of the land" and working out what's going where - making a map (prediction) of future trends.

Comment: But how can one **be better** at making a map(even of future trends)? I think one can most likely be better after making a map(to do something rather than just painting the picture).

Comment: It means that we become better at making predictions.